# VB.NET Array Arithmetic

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

Is there a built-in way to multiply every member of an array by some number in-place?

Example:

```
Dim volts () as Double = {1.243, 0.534, 5.343, 2.223, 4.334}
Dim millivolts (4) as Double = volts.MultiplyEachBy(1000) 'something like this
```

Comment: what version of .net framework are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Array.ConvertAll` method.

```
Array.ConvertAll(volts, Function(x) x * 1000)
```

**EDIT**

There is a small error in the sample code which needs to be corrected for the above to compile.  Remove the explicit size (4) from the variable type

```
Dim volts() As Double = {1.243, 0.534, 5.343, 2.223, 4.334}
```

Comment: @Steven, there is a slight error in how you are declaring the variable volts.  You need to remove the explicit size 4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in way to do this, but the best thing I could think to do would be to just create your own method. Something like

```
Public Function convertMilliamps(ByVal voltArray() As Double)
    For Each item AS Double In voltArray
        item = item * 1000 
    Next

Return voltArray()
End Function
```

then just do volts = convertMilliamps(volts)

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't work for each item because an item is a copy of the value, not the actual item from the array. This should work:

```
Public Function MultiplyArrayByScalar(ByRef arry As Double(), ByVal scaler As Double) As Double()

    Dim newArry As Double()
    Dim size As Integer = arry.GetLength(0)
    ReDim newArry(size - 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To size - 1
        newArry(i) = arry(i) * scaler
    Next

    Return newArry
End Function
```